# laravel Show only related data in search filter

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to create a search filter:

```
if ($request->has('street')) {
    $streets->where('name', 'like', '%'.$request->street.'%');
}

if ($request->has('house')) {
    $streets->whereHas('properties', function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('house_number', $request->house);
    });
}

return $streets->get();
```

This currently gets the `street` data. I want to do something like this `?street=b-34&house=21` and to display the `house` data.

At the moment I am only getting the `street` data.

Comment: Do you only want to return the `house` data when `house` is queried?

Comment: yes the house data against that street number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by using the `->with()` eloquent method. If the request has a `house` query, it will return all `properties` where the `house_number` equals the queried house number. Once found will attach to the returned results:

```
if (request()->has('street')) {
    $streets = $streets->where('name', 'like', '%'. request('street') .'%');
}

if (request()->has('house')) {
    $streets = $streets->with(['properties' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('house_number', request('house'));
    }]);
}

return $streets->get();
```

**Note:** I have changed `$request` to use the `request()` helper.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

?street= returns the results of street. What I'm trying to achieve is ?street=1&house=abc, should show only the house(properties )data, but it should be in street 1, the above queries return only the street.

Answer (score 3):

Your problems seems one every Laravel developer will go through one day. You forgot to return the query to the original constructor.

You have:

```
$streets->where('name', 'like', '%'. request('street') .'%');
```

when you should have:

```
$streets = $streets->where('name', 'like', '%'. request('street') .'%');
```

You are chaining the methods so you should have it return the original query constructor

**EDIT Based on  comments:**
Besides from not returning the query as I stated above you are using `whereHas` as @thisiskelvin have pointed out in his answer.

You should be using

```
if (request()->has('street')) {
    $streets = $streets->where('name', 'like', '%'. request('street') .'%');
}

if (request()->has('house')) {
    $streets = $streets->with(['properties' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('house_number', request('house'));
    }]);
}

return $streets->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. ?street= returns the results of street. What I'm trying to achieve is ?street=1&house=abc, should show only the house(properties )data, but it should be in street 1, the above queries return only the street data.